# Performance Overheads when Using Resource Files (.resx)

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, resx

Note, I am aware of the following questions on this topic:

1. [Are there any performance issues or caveats with resource (.resx) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278171/are-there-any-performance-issues-or-caveats-with-resource-resx-files)
2. [Are string resources (.resx) properties kept in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503887/are-string-resources-resx-properties-kept-in-memory)

et al. However, I don't find any of the answers in these questions satisfactory (they are not concrete enough).

I am also aware of the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1021kkz0(v=vs.71).aspx) pages on this topic, but these also seem to skimp on the technical information regarding the overheads of using resource files.

---

My predicament is that we are about to embark on the localisation of a reasonably large sized WinForms application. My concern at this stage is about the performance of accessing resources from a .resx file from within a nested loop for example. Currently for the small part of the code we have localised (Column Names, Row Headers etc. for `DataGridView` etc.) we are cashing the resources in global variables of the relevant class and using those.

**How are resources from the .resx accessed (are they included in the assembly at compile-time?) and is there a performance benefit from cashing those resources and using global variables for access?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

String resources are cached in memory. Look at the code that's generated in `"Resources.Designer.cs"`.

It uses a [`System.Resources.ResourceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx), and this does caching of the strings.

Also note [this ResourceManager constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsz7ac5.aspx). It mentions that you can change caching strategy:

> This constructor uses the system-provided ResourceSet implementation.
>   To use a custom resource file format, you should derive from the
>   ResourceSet class, override the GetDefaultReader and GetDefaultWriter
>   methods, and pass that type to the ResourceManager(String, Assembly,
>   Type) constructor. Using a custom ResourceSet can be **useful for
>   controlling resource caching policy** or supporting your own resource
>   file format, but is generally not necessary.

(my emphasis)

The [documentation for `ResourceSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourceset.aspx) explicitly says:

> > The ResourceSet class enumerates over an IResourceReader, loading every name and value, and storing them in a Hashtable

So we do know the exact caching strategy that you'll get by default.

[EDIT] Since you don't seem to believe me! :)

(1) Look at the documentation for the constructor [ResourceManager(string baseName,Assembly assembly)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsz7ac5.aspx). It states:

> > This constructor uses the system-provided ResourceSet implementation.

(2) Now look at the [documentation for ResourceSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourceset.aspx). It states:

> > The ResourceSet class enumerates over an IResourceReader, loading every name and value, and storing them in a Hashtable.

Therefore this caching behaviour is indeed documented in MSDN, and additionally you can verify that this is what is happening by using Resharper to inspect the implementation.

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for your reply. Most appreciated. Can you explain one other thing for me. To call a resource from the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsz7ac5.aspx) we do `ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("ExampleResources", typeof(Example).Assembly);
string greeting = rm.GetString("Greeting");` but I understand from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1142840/626442 that this can also be done via `Console.WriteLine(strings.Hello);` where the resource file is `strings.resx`. Whats's the difference?

Comment: Can you help with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523604/error-in-generation-of-resource-resource-design-cs-file

Comment: Using `strings.Hello` is just using the automatically-generated class in `Resources.Designer.cs`

Comment: I am still unsure about the caching of the strings. If you look in the Design.cs file, the property for the given resource calls `GetString(...)`, this to me does not appear to be caching the strings but retrieving them from the resource file at runtime... Moreover, the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/d17ax2xk.aspx) do not mention caching.

Comment: It calls `ResourceManager.GetString()` which ends up calling `ResourceSet.GetString()` which calls `ResourceSet.GetObjectInternal()` which looks up the string in a hash table. You can verify this by inspecting the code in Resharper. The MSDN docs *do* mention caching, and I provided the quote in my answer above.